# Definition of dicrete ordering

Tags: notation, model-theory

[image]

What means by "discrete ordering"?

Comment: Is your first paragraph a quotation? If so, what is the source that you are quoting?

Comment: http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/notes/model_theory_notes.pdf

Comment: Do you happen to know what the author of those notes means by an "ordering"? Is $\forall x\forall y(x\le y\vee y\le x)$ included among the axioms for an ordering?

Comment: I think the language of ordering is $L_{ord}=\{>,=\}$, and the tripple axiom is included only in total order. Otherwise $>$ is a relation $R$ with transitivity     $\forall a,b,c \in X: (aRb \wedge bRc) \Rightarrow aRc$

Comment: A ordering is usually called discrete if every element $x$ except the top one has an immediate successor $s(x)$, (i.e. $x < s(x)$ and there is nothing in between) and every element $y$ except the bottom one has an immediate predecessor $p(y)$ (i.e. $p(y) < y$ and there is nothing in between)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ordering is discrete if it is discrete when given the order topology (with basis of open intervals).

It means that every element except possibly the last one (if it exists) has an immediate successor, and every element except possibly the first one has an immediate predecessor.

In general, for any topological property $P$, an ordering has $P$ if it has $P$ when given the order topology (though sometimes other topologies are considered, depending upon the context, e.g. the initial topology or the terminal topology, but most likely not in this case).